# Why is TableView not displaying the column value whose value is calculated from other columns? Please suggest me some solutions

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

The form value is inserted into the database. But while fetching the data all the fields appear except the last two columns (result and grade) which is dependent on the value of other columns.
[This is the image of tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R10uV.png)
The code is shown below. For insert:

```
               btnAddNewStudent.setOnAction(actionEvent -> 
                    try {
                Connection connection = null;
                PreparedStatement statement = null;
                ResultSet resultSet = null;
                connection = DB.connectDb();
                connection.setAutoCommit(false);
                String query = "INSERT INTO java2(ID, StudentName, Quiz, A1,A2, Exam,result, grade) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?)";
                statement = connection.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                int counter = 1;
                statement.setString(counter++, studentId.getText());
                statement.setString(counter++, studentName.getText());
                statement.setString(counter++, quizMarks.getText());
                statement.setString(counter++, assignmentOneMarks.getText());
                statement.setString(counter++, assignmentTwoMarks.getText());
                statement.setString(counter++, examMarks.getText());

                double totalmarks = Double.parseDouble(quizMarks.getText()) * 0.05
                        + Double.parseDouble(assignmentOneMarks.getText()) * 0.15
                        + Double.parseDouble(assignmentTwoMarks.getText()) * 0.2
                        + Double.parseDouble(examMarks.getText()) * 0.6;

                String grade = "";
                if (totalmarks >= 85 && totalmarks < 100) {
                    grade = "HD";
                } else if (totalmarks >= 75 && totalmarks < 85) {
                    grade = "DI";
                } else if (totalmarks >= 65 && totalmarks < 75) {
                    grade = "CR";
                } else if (totalmarks >= 50 && totalmarks < 65) {
                    grade = "PS";
                } else if (totalmarks > 50) {
                    grade = "Fail";
                }

                statement.setString(counter++, Double.toString(totalmarks));
                statement.setString(counter++, grade);

                statement.executeUpdate();
                connection.commit();
                this.alert("Save", "Successful!", Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);

                data.clear();
```

The insert part works fine and insert the value in the database table.

And code for fetching the data

//assigning data in the cell of table

```
    TableColumn name = new TableColumn("Name");
    name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

    TableColumn id = new TableColumn("Id");
    id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));

    TableColumn quiz = new TableColumn("Quiz");
    quiz.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quiz"));

    TableColumn a1 = new TableColumn("A1");
    a1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("a1"));

    TableColumn a2 = new TableColumn("A2");
    a2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("a2"));

    TableColumn exam = new TableColumn("Exam");
    exam.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("exam"));

    TableColumn result = new TableColumn("Results");
    result.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("result"));

    TableColumn grades = new TableColumn("Grade");
    grades.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("grades"));

    table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
    //adding all the data in the cell of the table
    table.getColumns().addAll(name, id, quiz, a1, a2, exam, result,grades);
    table.setItems(data);
    Connection connection = null;
    connection = DB.connectDb();
    ResultSet resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from java2");
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        String studName = resultSet.getString("StudentName");
        String studId = resultSet.getString("ID");

        double quizMark = Double.parseDouble(resultSet.getString("Quiz"));
        double a1mark = Double.parseDouble(resultSet.getString("A1"));
        double a2mark = Double.parseDouble(resultSet.getString("A2"));
        double examMark = Double.parseDouble(resultSet.getString("Exam"));
        double totalmarks=Double.parseDouble(resultSet.getString("result"));
        String grade=resultSet.getString("grade");
        System.out.println(grade);
        data.add(new Student(studName, studId, quizMark, a1mark, a2mark, examMark, totalmarks, 
         grade));
    }
```

And the code for Student class is given below

```
public class Student {
private final String name;
private final String id;
private final double quiz;
private final double a1;
private final double a2;
private final double exam;
private final double result;
private final String grade;


public Student(String name, String id, double quiz, double a1, double a2, 
    double exam, double result, String grade) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.quiz = quiz;
    this.a1 = a1;
    this.a2 = a2;
    this.exam = exam;
    this.result = result;
    this.grade = grade;

}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String studentName) {
    studentName = this.name;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String studentId) {
    studentId = this.id;
}

public double getQuiz() {
    return quiz;
}

public void setQuiz(double quizMarks) {
    quizMarks = this.quiz;
}

public double getA1() {
    return a1;
}

public void setA1(double assignmentOneMarks) {
    assignmentOneMarks = this.a1;
}

public double getA2() {
    return a2;
}

public void setA2(double assignmentTwoMarks) {
    assignmentTwoMarks = this.a2;
}

public double getExam() {
    return exam;
}

public void setExam(double exam) {
    exam = this.exam;
}

public double getresult() {
    return result;
}

public void setresult(double result) {
    result = this.result;
}

public String getgrade() {
    return grade;
}

public void setgrade(String grade) {
    grade = this.grade;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you also show the code for your Student class. I believe you may be missing the getters for the grade and results.

Comment: Does your `System.out.println(grade)` (just before the `data.add(new Student` ) display the correct value ?

Comment: @Bernie I have it. Please help me. I will edit and post it. Please have a look.

Comment: @racraman yes it does. You can see the value in the console in the image.

Comment: if you have control about the Student class, let it expose properties (vs. mere getters/setters) and use those in a valueFactory (vs. PropertyValueFactory) - doing so will by-pass any spelling issues, the compiler will tell you when you get it wrong

Answer (score 2):

Your getters (and setters) for result and grade are named with all lower case letters, contrary to the standard naming convention where the property name should start capitalised.  This means that when JavaFx cannot find the method name it expects for these columns.

So replace your declarations with :

```
public double getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(double result) {
    result = this.result;
}

public String getGrade() {
    return grade;
}

public void setGrade(String grade) {
    grade = this.grade;
}
```

EDIT:
Also the PropertyValueFactory name must also match :

```
grades.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("grade"));
```

Comment: Thank you. The result is displayed but not grade now.

Comment: Just editted to hopefully fix that one - change String argument "grades" to "grade"

Comment: A big thanks to you. It works like magic now. Thank you so much.

Comment: @sagarneupane This is why it's often recommended to avoid `PropertyValueFactory` and instead use a lambda as the latter will provide compile-time safety (and as a small bonus, the lambda approach avoids reflection). In other words, you should have `setCellFactory(data -> data.getValue().gradeProperty())`. Although, since you don't appear to be using JavaFX properties in your `Student` class, you'll have to wrap `data.getValue().getGrade()` in a property (e.g. `SimpleDoubleProperty` or a read only version); in this case, you'd also have to add custom handling for inline editing (if required).